# How to prevent Exchange 2007 users to see other users in the same address list

Tags: exchange-2007, exchange

I am running a Hosted Exchange environment based on EX2007sp2. We have a project running, which will create several users on the same email domain, but since this will be a "common user domain", I would like to prevent the users from see other users in the same email domain.

Segregating adress list is OK, between companies, but this one is addressed to segregation users from each others.

Any sharing around experiences regarding this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Option A)
You can hide users from the address list by going into the exchange management console and then to mailboxes, go to the mailbox properties in the general tab is a checkbox hide users address from address list.
You would need to do this to every user that you want not be visible.

If there are some users you want become visible, you would want to setup a specific address list, make those users a member of that address list.

keep in mind if we are talking a lot of users, add them to groups and set these permissions group based.

After making this change update your GAL and OAB.

Option B)  You can add all of the users you want not visible into a group and then edit the ACLs on the Address Lists, select Deny - Read rights to the address lists in which you do not want these users viewing users on.